# Installer not creating instead of compiling install.xml

Tags: izpack

I have given the following command at the `bin` directory of `Izpack` like this

```
C:\Program Files\IzPack\bin>compile D:\ant\guage install.xml
```

Is this the correct way to give ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are missing arguments. Please consult the getting started section in the [IzPack online documentation](http://izpack.org/documentation/getting-started.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
compile install.xml -b . -o install.jar -k standard
```

**install.xml** is in bin folder. It will generate **install.jar** file.

To make **exe** file [see this](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=350).